# Conditional Probability- hard

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Hi guys can someone please help me with the following question:
[image]
I have come up with the following:

a. P(\$20) = (2/3)

b. Since Tom states that Jenny used a $10 note we have to assume he didnt correctly identify it and by assuming independence between these two events; P(Jenny used 20) = 0.1*(2/3) = 1/15.

c. Jenny must have correctly identified the 20 note thus P(Jenny used 20) = 0.8*(1/15)=4/75.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: FWIW, this doesn't merit a downvote IMO (so long as the tag is added & our policies are followed). The OP identified this as a homework problem and has put some work into trying to answer it on her own.

Comment: @zero nobody has failed, nobody has to leave... There is a difference between "failing the community" and posting off-topic question...

Comment: Welcome to our site, Jenny!  Please forgive the unfortunate negative comments that had appeared (and are now deleted).  As the remaining comments attest, they reflected a misunderstanding by one individual, rather than the opinion of this community.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edits because they reduced the question to nonsense, thereby destroying any value in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

For (2), essentially you need to deal with both cases which make it a USD 20 note.
Either it was a 20 (2/3 probability like you stated), and he guessed incorrectly that it was a 10. Like you wrote, that hs a 1/15 probability of occurring. The alternative, is that it was a 10, and he guessed correctly that this was the case. This has a 0.9*(1/3) probability of occurring. Now you just need to likelyhood of the foremer out of the sample P(20|tom says 10) = (0.1*(2/3))/(0.1*(2/3)+0.9*(1/3))

Answer (score 0):

I agree 100% with @Moshe (+1) on b.

Regarding C.  I am assuming that Jenny’s and Tom’s percentages are conditionally independent of one another.

$$P(20|TomSaid10 and JennySaid20) = \frac{P(TomSaid10 and JennySaid20|20)*P(20)}{P(TomSaid10 and JennySaid20)}$$

$$P(20|TomSaid10 and JennySaid20) = \frac{0.1*0.8*\frac{2}{3}}{P(TomSaid10 and JennySaid20|20)*P(20)+ P(TomSaid10 and JennySaid20|10)*P(10)}$$

$$P(20|TomSaid20 and JennySaid10) = \frac{0.08*\frac{2}{3}}{0.1*0.8*\frac{2}{3}+0.9*0.3*\frac{1}{3}}$$

$P(20|TomSaid20 and JennySaid10) = \frac{16}{16+27}$$=\frac{16}{43}\approx0.37$